# Hibernate/JPA map Result of native Query to non-Entity holding Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I do have 3 Entities and want to Cross-Join them. As I do not need to create a new Entity for this I just wanted to map the by fetching with a native Query:

```
EntityA{
    ...
    String someValue;
}

EntityB{
    ...
    String someValue;
}

EntityC{
    ...
    String someValue;
}
```

And the CrossJoined Object

```
CrossJoinedFoo{
    EntityA entityA;
    EntityB entityB;
    EntityC entityC;
}
```

I am using it like:

```
private static final String _SELECT_CROSS_JOIN_ENTITIES = "SELECT * FROM "
            + "EntityA"
            + ", "
            + "EntityB"
            + ", "
            + "EntityC"
            + " WHERE (1=1) "
            + " AND " + "EntityA.someValue = :someValue"
            + " AND " + "EntityB.someValue = :someValue"
            + " AND " + "EntityC.someValue = :someValue";

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(_SELECT_CROSS_JOIN_ENTITIES);
query.setParameter(":someValue", "foo");
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for a HQL query and use the result class strategy.
Just remember to add a constructor to CrossJoinedFoo accepting 3 entities in appropriate order:

```
private static final String _SELECT_CROSS_JOIN_ENTITIES = 
            "SELECT new my.package.CrossJoinedFoo(a,b,c) FROM "
            + "EntityA a"
            + ", "
            + "EntityB b"
            + ", "
            + "EntityC c"
            + " WHERE (1=1) "
            + " AND " + "a.someValue = :someValue"
            + " AND " + "b.someValue = :someValue"
            + " AND " + "c.someValue = :someValue";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(_SELECT_CROSS_JOIN_ENTITIES);
query.setParameter(":someValue", "foo");

List<CrossJoinedFoo> result = query.list();
```

Just remember to change the package to an appropriate one.

Comment: Simpler approach :) +1 however you lost the type safety

Comment: Why should the type safety be lost?

Comment: Because the name of the resulting class is within the query String and so not handled as a type by the compiler

Comment: @Code.It Note that this approach use a JPQL query and the resulting entities will so be managed which is not the case when using a native sql query. If you don't get the consequence, prefer this answer over mine

Comment: As I just use them for readOnly purpose, I do not care about the managed state :D

Answer (score 1):

Using `@SqlResultSetMapping` with [`@ConstructorResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)

Beware that the resulted entities won't be [managed](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm#BABIAAGE)